# "Parser Error" After moving the website to the server

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error

My website is working totally fine on local host but when I moved the website to the server I couldn't open the website, I got the following error:

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/applications/GeneralMaster.master' does not exist.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/GeneralMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
```

I'm using Telerik menu and I have included the dll file in Bin folder, I tried to build and rebuild the website but It didn't work and when I searched the problem some says it's because Ajax extentions, is that possible and how I can fix the error?

I'm working with ASP.NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your deployment servers website is running under the correct application pool. Double check this. Also double check your web.config file that it has the correct bindings and handlers for Telerik and and Ajax Extensions, are you using Ajax Script Manager or RadScriptManager? Could you post a bit more info on the error your getting? and the steps leading up to the error?

Comment: Thank you for willing to help. I knew the problem, it was because the domain is not created probably and the problem was solved after recreating the domain .